# Batch Insert Exception in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I get a batch `insert exception` having `ERRORCODE "-4229"` and `SQLSTATE` `null` on executing the Prepared Statement. `getNextException()` didn't work either.

Comment: It gives not useful info, except for the place where the error is thrown and the ERRORCODE

Answer (score 2):

[According to the manual](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjcsqc.html), you should use `SQLException.getMessage()` to obtain the error details.